# How to hide product attribute from add new product in admin area?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

I have created a `product attribute` name "testcheck". I am trying to hide this attribute from add new product section only but want to show the edit product mode. so I can put the test value for this attribute once the product has been created.

Is there any way or idea or data provider. Please suggest.